# what is the role of wcf in silverlight applications?

Tags: wcf, ria

i am new to the concept of silverlight and understood few things from this site.
i want to clear my doubt that what is the role of wcf ria services in silverlight applications?
what do we mean by domain services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain services are the one who gives you access to a remote repositories using WCF technology.  That Silverlight compact .Net framework is on the clientside which needs to access services through cloud (internet) in able to interact data to the users.

You can start in http://www.silverlight.net

Happy reading!

Comment: I am unable to understand the second line of your answer.please elaborate a bit.

Comment: The Silverlight framework is a compact .Net that is being installed on the client side (users) just like a Flash Plugin.  Since application created in Silverlight resides in the client, they don't have direct access to a database unlike the Destop/Windows Forms applications, thats why they need a bridge or a medium just like web services, WCF Services to communicate to the databases.

Comment: [Silverlight Arch](http://silverlighttutorialsweb.blogspot.com/2009/08/silverlight-architecture.html) this is another link for you to read in able to understand the way Silverlight application works.

Answer (score 3):

In Silverlight, you do not connect to a database directly - your Silverlight app runs on the client machine after all. The client-side UI (Silverlight) and the database / backend are strictly separated. The number of classes that the Silverlight runtime has to offer is (by design) quite limited, and things like direct database access are not amongst those classes available.

The way your SL app gets its data is through a WCF service (Domain service, or WCF Data Service) running on some server, which accesses the database on your behalf. This part usually runs on your web/app server and has access to your database or other backend servers.

Comment: thanks alot,but what do you meant by the line"which accesses the database on your behalf"?

Comment: @iti: your SL app doesn't access the database itself - it sends a request (over WCF) to your server app, which then accesses the database, gets the data, and returns it back as the response for that request